# Importing data from txt file into C program

Tags: c, file, struct, scanf

I am trying to import data from a txt file into a C program. The txt file format is something like this:

```
George_Washington 1789-1797 Unaffiliated
John_Adams 1797-1801 Federalist
Thomas_Jefferson 1801-1809 Democratic_Republican
James_Madison 1809-1817 Democratic_Republican
James_Monroe 1817-1825 Democratic_Republican
John_Quincy_Adams 1825-1829 Democratic_Republican
Andrew_Jackson 1829-1837 Democrat
Martin_Van_Buren 1837-1841 Democrat
... (total 45 lines)
```

I have a struct to hold my variables

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[30];
    char date[10];
    char party[25];
}presidents;
```

I am trying to move data from the txt into my main function into the separate arrays: name, date, party.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    int i = 0;
    presidents presidents_data[45];

    file = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    while (3 == fscanf(file, "%30s %10s %25s", &presidents_data[i].name,
    &presidents_data[i].date, &presidents_data[i].party))
    {
        printf("");
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: %s, Years: %s, Party: %s\n", presidents_data[i].name,
        presidents_data[i].date, presidents_data[i].party);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error message when I compile that says "format specifies type 'char **' but the argument has type 'char (*)[30]'"

It looks like the variables aren't matching up or something.

I'm pretty new to coding so any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't need the `&` in front of the strings in the `fscanf`. Also, the character limit should be one less than the string size, i.e. `"%29s %9s %24s"`.

Comment: `while (3 == fscanf(file, "%30s %10s %25s", &presidents_data[i].name,
    &presidents_data[i].date, &presidents_data[i].party))` You can remove the '&'s here, the character arrays decay into pointers to the 1st element.